# Excel, Compile VBAProject - change the order of the compilation of modules

Tags: excel, module, excel-2007, vba

Lets suppose that we are in the Visual Basic Editor, in Excel 2007. We create one module, named `modGlass`:

```
Sub VolatileGlass()
    Dim Glass As shiny_surface

End Sub
```

and then we create a second module, named `modMetal`:

```
Sub durableMetal()
    Dim metal As metal_compound

End Sub
```

[image]

Subs in both modules contain the error: `"User-defined type not defined."`

When I compile the project by using the *Debug: Compile VBAProject* menu entry, the `modGlass` module always compiles first. If I:

- double click on the `modMetal` module and compile (it?) or
- rename `modMetal` to `amodMetal` (so that the metal module is now first in the module tree hierarchy of the project)

still, the `modGlass` module is compiled first.

The question: if I have a project with multiple modules in VBE, is there a way to specify, in what sequence will the modules be compiled?

I don't really need this feature, but I'm just curious if there is some quick way to do it. I'm using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules are not compiled based on their names but in the sequence they were created. So it really doesn't matter if you put "a" before `modMetal`

To test it create two modules. Ensure both modules have errors. When you compile it you will notice that the module which was created first will be compiled first. Now delete the 1st module and recreate it. This time when you compile it, the 2nd one (not the newly created) gets compiled first :)

No, unfortunately there is no direct way(AFAIK) to specify that sequence. However the dirty way to do it is based on what I suggested above. Copy all the data to notepad and then delete all the modules and then recreate them from scratch (in the order in which you want to compile them)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To specify the sequence, I've originally came up with importing and exporting the modules back, but I your way of just deleting / recreating them is faster. Cheers.